# working on how to display a map view in Iphone

Tags: iphone

I can display the map view for specific location. However, I dont know how to zoom in or out in simulator. Please any one how to do it, advice me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hold down the Alt/Option key while in the simulator, you can do two-finger gestures such as pinch zooming and  rotating.